# Norm on following matrices

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

[image]

I know that for infinite, ||A|| = max(absolute values of added first row, second row, third row). But how do you find the for p = 2 and F?

Comment: p=2: This is the largest absolute value of all eigenvalues. p=F: Treat the matrix as a vector and compute the usual Euclidian norm.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp : Ffor p=F, you said usual Euclidian norm, #sqrt(-9^2 + 5^2 .....8^2). is this right?

Comment: Almost. (-9)^2 instead of -9^2.

Comment: oh yes that's right. Thank you so much

Comment: My pleasure. :o)